# How to configure automatic calculation in a column in oracle sql who's information is in another column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this Fact Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FACTPRODUCTSALES (
    TRANSACTIONID      NUMBER
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 )
    PRIMARY KEY,
    SALESINVOICENUMBER INT NOT NULL,
    SALESDATEKEY       NUMBER CONSTRAINT SALES_KEY_FK REFERENCES DIMDATE (DATEKEY),
    SALESTIMEKEY       NUMBER CONSTRAINT SALESTIME_KEY_FK REFERENCES DIM_TIME (TIMEKEY),
    STOREID            NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT STORE_ID_FK REFERENCES DIMSTORES (STOREID),
    CUSTOMERID         NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_ID_FK REFERENCES DIMCUSTOMER (CUSTOMERID),
    PRODUCTID          NUMBER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_ID_FK REFERENCES DIMPRODUCT (PRODUCTKEY),
    SALESPERSONID      INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT SALESPERSON_ID_FK REFERENCES DIMSALESPERSON ( SALESPERSONID ),
    QUANTITY          FLOAT,
    SALESTOTALCOST    INT as (DIMPRODUCT.PRODUCTSALESCOST * QUANTITY),
    PRODUCTACTUALCOST INT as (DIMPRODUCT.PRODUCTACTUALCOST * QUANTITY),
    DEVIATION         FLOAT
);
```

As you can see in the `SALESTOTALCOST` and `PRODUCTACTUALCOST,` I want to automatically calculate their values each time I insert something on this table depending on the value inside of the `DIMPRODUCT.PRODUCTSALESCOST` and `DIMPRODUCT.PRODUCTACTUALCOST` depending on what's the ID inserted by the user in the field of `DIMPRODUCT` but of course, this code wouldn't work.

Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you want a _view_ instead?

Comment: Lookup the concept of [virtual columns](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1)

Comment: For the calculated columns I'd create a view. Or, if the view performance in unsatisfactory, I'd create materialized view logs for dimproduct and FACTPRODUCTSALES (which would no longer include the computed columns) and a materialized view. Not sure if that would work with refresh on commit would work for that materialized view for I do not know how factproductsales is to be joined  to dimproduct.

Comment: Prices change. Either you have a table containing the price history, so you can always see which prices were valid at a particular time (DATEKEY/TIMEKEY) or you should store the columns PRODUCTSALESCOST and PRODUCTACTUALCOST in the FACTPRODUCTSALES table. In the former case you would create a view to tell you the total prices, in the latter case you'd create virtual computed columns in the table instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, don't do that.

Either:

1. Create a `VIEW` and generate the totals in the view by joining the two tables.
2. If you want to materialise the data then create a `MATERIALIZED VIEW`.
3. Use a (compound) trigger to update the table when the dependant columns are modified.

You do not provide details of the `DIMPRODUCT` table or how the two tables are related so providing code is impossible.